# virtuemart product not getting fedex v2 rates, what attributes fedex required?

Tags: virtuemart, fedex

I added some custom products in virtuemart from my custom component and added its weight and other attributes but fedex v2, does not get shipping rates for my custom added products while it get the shipping rates for other normal products. I want to know that which attribute does fedex v2 use?  So that I can check about those. USPS is also getting rates for normal products and also for my custom product. But there seems to be some attribute that is wrong with my newly added custom product. So I want to know that what are the required attributes for fedex v2?  Please tell if you know this or if you know fedex v2 attributes used from virtuemart then that is better. Because without that I think it is useless to change so many attributes one by one and without any certainty.

Please tell whatever you know about that , any clue will be appreciated as I don't know much about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer by myself :) The missing field was  "max_per_package" and entered 9999 to it and it worked:)